# Using "toda" properly

Tags: gramática

Assuming that **a** and **b** are correct, is the construction of **c** correct? Also are there better/simpler ways of conveying the same information?

> a) las cortinas en toda la casa son grises. (*in every room*)

Meaning: "The curtains throughout the house are gray".

> b) las cortinas en todas las casas son grises (*in at least one room of every house*)

Meaning: "The curtains in every house are gray".

> c) las cortinas en toda la casa en todas las casas son grises. (*in every room of every house*)

Intending to mean: "The curtains throughout every house are gray".

Comment: I would interpret your (b) as meaning what you want (c) to mean.  I would have said _Algunas cortinas en cada casa_ to get what you want (b) to mean.

Comment: @mdewey Is right, like in English, "las" mean "the" meaning all of them, in English you have to say "some" and in Spanish this is translated to "Algunas"

Comment: Las casas en esta zona tienen puras cortinas grises. Sounds like a town in the old East Germany, with no paint to liven up the gray cement. I know in Cuba that was because of the embargo, but I've never understood why East German apartment buildings had to look so depressing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would say each sentence, using "toda" everywhere:

> a) Las cortinas son grises en toda la casa.

*The* curtains (all of them) are grey in *all* the house (i.e. every room).
Alternatively,

> a) Todas las cortinas son grises en la casa.

*All* the curtains are grey in the house (implying every room that actually has curtains).

> b) Todas las casas tienen cortinas grises.

*All* the houses have grey curtains. By dropping "the", you don't imply *all* the curtains anymore, just some of them.
You can be more explicit and say:

> b) Todas las casas tienen alguna(s) cortina(s) gris(es).

*All* the houses have some grey curtain(s).

> c) Todas las cortinas son grises en todas las casas.

*All* the curtains are grey in *all* the houses.

Notice, however, that c) doesn't logically follow from a) + b), because in a) you are referring to one house in particular, and you didn't say that all houses are the same. Just that all of them have some grey curtains.

Comment: I think the sentences a) and c) can be reworded to be more "natural": 
a) Todas las cortinas de la casa son grises.
c) Todas las cortinas de todas las casas son grises.

Comment: what about En todas las cosas hay cortinas grises 
esto se refiere a que en la union de todas las cosas hay cortinas grises, o que debe haber cotinas grises en cada una de las csas ?, para diferenciarlo tendria que decir "entre todas las casas hay cortinas grises"?